# Postgres rails doesn't recognize user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rails-postgresql, pg

So my rails app gives me the "We're sorry, but something went wrong."  When I check the logs, I see

```
PG::Error (FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
):
```

However, when I then do this (note I believe that I never added a password to role ubuntu):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser ubuntu
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "ubuntu" already exists
```

I'm running this on an ubuntu ec2 instance with nginx server.

EDIT: I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling postgres, and completely broke it, so I won't be able to accept any answer here.

Comment: These are presumably two different installations. Users are listed in the pg_user view (or pg_roles).

Comment: Have you tried deleting ubuntu user and recreating it?

Comment: Richard what do you mean by two different installations?  I'm running two versions of postgres?