# Rails app: errors moving from postgres to mysql on ubuntu ec2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql

So after some problems with postgres on rails ala this [Postgres rails doesn't recognize user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342553/postgres-rails-doesnt-recognize-user), I uninstalled postgres and decided to try mysql for my rails app.  I installed mysql successfully, and set up my database.yml as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db_development
  user: root
  pool: 5
  password: ##
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db_test
  user: root
  pool: 5
  password: #
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db_production
  username: root
  pool: 5
  password: ##
  timeout: 5000
```

I also did rake db:create:all and rake db:migrate.  However, I get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" and when I check the logs, I get PG (postgres errors) like this:

```
PG::Error (FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
):
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
```

Later, it references a PG database that was previously mentioned in database.yml and no longer exists:

```
PG::Error (FATAL:  database "db/production" does not exist
):
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
```

I have no idea what's going on.  FWIW I'm using ruby 2.0, rails 3.2.13, nginx, and phusion passenger

Comment: Did you restart nginx after changing the database.yml?

Comment: Yeah, I restarted it.

Comment: What gems do you have? You need to have the mysql2 gem installed.

Comment: Yup I have the mysql2 gem.  It actually shows some mysql2 errors much later in the logs but I don't know why it even mentions PG.

Comment: That's really strange... I'm not sure if what would be going on if you have mysql2 errors and postgresql errors in the same file.

Comment: Figured it out, I feel incredibly stupid.  Those errors were because the log file kept old errors from before.  They were not from the latest run of the app.